# Import starcounter project into visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, starcounter

I have a fully operational starcounter (fusion of a C# VM and a DBMS) project, which I had to port into another machine. I did it by going into:

"File -> New -> Project from existing code"

In the following window, I chose Visual C# as the project type, and then I specified where the folder with the files was, along with the output type, which can only be one of three:

- Console Application
- Windows Application
- Class Library

But nothing in this window allow me to choose the imported application as being a "starcounter application"... And after the project is imported, in the "using Starcounter" import, I keep getting the error "the type or namespace name 'Starcounter' could not be found". Any idea on what am I doing wrong? I am using Visual Studio 2013 ultimate!

PS: More info about starcounter here: http://starcounter.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starcounter's project templates are only available for new empty projects and not avaialble for new projects from existing code.

To continue development on another machine move entire project, i.e., source code together with project and solution files, to new machine and just open the project. It works well if the same version of Visual Studio is used. You can also test if it will work with a later version of Visual Studio, which will require to convert project.

Another approach is to create new empty Starcounter project and add source code files to it. It is important to add both typed json files with code behind files.

Comment: So easy... Moving the entire project did the trick for me. Thank you so much!